# How to mock WCF client using Moq?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq, system.reactive

In my project I am using: SL5+ MVVM+ Prism + WCF + Rx + Moq + Silverlight Unit Testing Framework.

I am new to unit-testing and have recently started into DI, Patterns (MVVM) etc. Hence the following code has a lot of scope for improvement (please fell free to reject the whole approach I am taking if you think so).

To access my WCF services, I have created a factory class like below (again, it can be flawed, but please have a look):

```
namespace SomeSolution
{
    public class ServiceClientFactory:IServiceClientFactory
    {
        public CourseServiceClient GetCourseServiceClient()
        {
            var client = new CourseServiceClient();
            client.ChannelFactory.Faulted += (s, e) => client.Abort();
            if(client.State== CommunicationState.Closed){client.InnerChannel.Open();}
            return client;
        }

        public ConfigServiceClient GetConfigServiceClient()
        {
            var client = new ConfigServiceClient();
            client.ChannelFactory.Faulted += (s, e) => client.Abort();
            if (client.State == CommunicationState.Closed) { client.InnerChannel.Open(); }
            return client;
        }

        public ContactServiceClient GetContactServiceClient()
        {
            var client = new ContactServiceClient();
            client.ChannelFactory.Faulted += (s, e) => client.Abort();
            if (client.State == CommunicationState.Closed) { client.InnerChannel.Open(); }
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

It implements a simple interface as below:

```
public interface IServiceClientFactory
{
    CourseServiceClient GetCourseServiceClient();
    ConfigServiceClient GetConfigServiceClient();
    ContactServiceClient GetContactServiceClient();
}
```

In my VMs I am doing DI of the above class and using Rx to call WCF as below:

```
var client = _serviceClientFactory.GetContactServiceClient();
try
{

    IObservable<IEvent<GetContactByIdCompletedEventArgs>> observable =
        Observable.FromEvent<GetContactByIdCompletedEventArgs>(client, "GetContactByIdCompleted").Take(1);

    observable.Subscribe(
        e =>
            {
                if (e.EventArgs.Error == null)
                {                                    
                    //some code here that needs to be unit-tested

                }
            },
        ex =>
        {
            _errorLogger.ProcessError(GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ErrorSource.Observable, "", -1, ex);
        }
        );
    client.GetContactByIdAsync(contactid, UserInformation.SecurityToken);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _errorLogger.ProcessError(GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ErrorSource.Code, "", -1, ex);
}
```

Now I want to build unit tests (yes, its not TDD). But I don't understand where to start. With Moq I can't mock the BlahServiceClient. Also no svcutil generated interface can help because async methods are not part of the auto-generated IBlahService interface. I may prefer to extend (through partial classes etc) any of the auto generated classes, but I would hate to opt for manually building all the code that svcutil can generate (frankly considering time and budget).

Can someone please help? Any pointer in the right direction would help me a lot.

Comment: "//some code here that needs to be unit-tested" -  What kind of code ? Because i think that you are testing the wrong thing. If you want to unit test the code then test it in isolated scenario without WCF and all the service infrastructure.

Comment: That's very true Michal. I should refactor my code to isolate other logic from WCF call. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user697942 There's not much to refactor here. Just put your "some code" in it's own method and test that method. No need to test the WCF stuff then.

Comment: @Michal, in my case, I just got done creating a service.  We want unit tests to make sure making calls via wsdl always works so we need a sweet of tests for that.  So I'm trying to unit test my service methods...as if I'm a client consuming the Web Service.  So my intention is to call methods specified in the WSDL as a hypothetical client/consumer of my web service.  Now on the other hand I might also want to create unit tests right in my SErvice project itself to test the methods?  Not sure about what to unit test.

Comment: what is client.ChannelFactory doing?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict In this case you should focus on integration testing. Write simple scripts that are making HTTP calls and check if the response is OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When mocking your service client you are actually mocking one of the interfaces it implements.  So in your case it may be `IContactService`.

The generated code implements both `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IContactService>` and `IContactService`.   Your dependency provider (in your case a factory) is returning `ContactServiceClient` - change this to `IContactService` for starters.  This will aid your DI now and in the future.

Ok, you're already have an abstract factory and now they return your service interface `IContactService`.  You're using interfaces only now so the mocking is quite trivial.

First some assumptions about the code you're trying to exercise.  The code snippet provided messages both the abstract factory and the service client.  Provided that the **//some code here that needs to be unit-tested**  section is not going to interact with any other **dependencies** then you're looking to mock out both the factory and the service client so that you test is isolated to just the method body code.

I've made an adjustment for the sake of example.  Your interfaces:

```
public class Contact {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IContactService {
    Contact GetContactById(int contactid);
}

public interface IContactServiceFactory {
    IContactService GetContactService();
}
```

Then your test would look summing like this:

```
public void WhateverIsToBeTested_ActuallyDoesWhatItMustDo() {

    // Arrange
    var mockContactService = new Mock<IContactService>();
    mockContactService.Setup(cs => cs.GetContactById(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(new Contact { Name = "Frank Borland" });

    var fakeFactory = new Mock<IContactServiceFactory>();
    fakeFactory.Setup(f => f.GetContactService())
        .Returns(mockContactService.Object);

    /* i'm assuming here that you're injecting the dependency intoto your factory via the contructor - but 
     * assumptions had to be made as not all the code was provided
     */
    var yourObjectUnderTest = new MysteryClass(fakeFactory.Object);

    // Act
    yourObjectUnderTest.yourMysteryMethod();

    // Assert
    /* something mysterious, but expected, happened */            

}
```

**EDIT: Mocking the Async Methods**

The async generated methods are not part of your service methods and is created by WCF as part of the Client class.  To mock those as an Interface do the following:

1. Extract the Interface of the `ContactServiceClient` class.  In VS it's simply a right-click (on the class name), refactor, extract interface.  And choose only the applicable methods.
2. The `ContactServiceClient` class is partial so create a **new class file** and redefine the ContactServiceClient class to implement the new `IContactServiceClient` interface you just extracted.

   ```
   public partial class ContactServiceClient : IContactServiceClient {
   }
   ```

Like such and now the client class ALSO implements the new interface with the selected async methods.  When refreshing your service interface and the service class is re-generated - you don't have to re-extract the interface as you've created a *separate partial class* with the interface reference.

3. Create a new factory to return the new interface

   ```
   public interface IContactServiceClientFactory {
       IContactServiceClient GetContactServiceClient();
   }
   ```
4. Modify the test to work with that interface.

Comment: Thanks, but IContactService hasn't got GetContactByIdAsync (or any async method) defined in it out of the box, which is the main issue. I don't know why Microsoft did that.

Comment: You don't have to hand code the async interface to achieve the same result. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt: Your solution to the Async problem is problematic, as the entire idea of code generation is that it "just works". If the OP switches to use the manually-extracted ICourseServiceClient, then next time the IDL changes, he will have to re-extract the interface in order to use the changes in his code. Doable - but annoying and error-prone.

Comment: Helpful answer. However, the "Contact" and "Course" classes are messed up in your code, related to the OP's question. Would you mind using just one of those?

Comment: @Marcel: Well spotted! thanks.  I've corrected the references to Course.  The OP ommitted defining the ContactService interface when it was clearly being used in the code example - i've added that now.

Comment: @splintor: If the WCF team provided us with the ServiceClient interface with the generated code then it would definitely help and avoid extra work by unit testers down the line.  Thanks for your input.  Perhaps you have a better/alternative approach to this? i'd like to learn.

Comment: Actually I ended up creating ServiceAgent classes (with related interfaces), moving all WCF service related code in these.

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt: Sorry, but I don't have any better alternative... :(

Comment: so are you saying when you mock a service, you still add the wsdl reference to your Test.csproj?

Comment: And are you creating an instance of the generated proxy Contact or the original DTO before it was consumed and serialized by WCF and into a wsdl? (in other words would you want to create an instance of the original DTO used in your WCF services code that you use ..data contracts?)?  Assuming you do not have any attributes, it's just a POCO without any WCF attributes

Comment: I'm mocking the service implementation so all i need is the service contract interface and if needed the DTO's (as they are used with the contract).  No WSDL or service implementions.

Comment: that's an aweful lot of code just to basically return IMyService.SomeMethod

Comment: what is the YourMysteryClass specifically meaning in the context of all this?

Comment: The MysteryClass is a concrete class, of yours, that uses the service (and therefore has a dependency on that service).  This answer shows how to mock out that dependency so that you are only testing your concrete class and perhaps the way it interacts with and responds to the services in the ways that you intended.  When the service is mocked - you can simulate any interaction and response with it - thereby making sure your concrete class works with the dependency correctly.

Comment: A nice update to this... In .Net Core or higher with proxies generated with dotnet-svcutil, the interface already implements the async methods. So you don't have to extract the interface and make a new partial class of your service client just to mock it. 

For whatever reason, these interfaces don't start with "I" like C# convention normally would. For instance, the interface for ContactServiceClient would be ContactService. I believe that's the same as it used to be but it threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

For .net core i composed the follow snippet:

```
// Set up the mock client for the RelatieSoapClient.
var relatieSoapClientMock = new Mock<RelatieSoapClient>(
    new WSHttpBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000"));

// Set up the mock response for the Get method.
var relatieSoapMock = new Mock<RelatieSoap>();
relatieSoapMock.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<GetRequest>())).Returns(new GetResponse
{
    GetResult = resultContainer
});

// Set up the protected CreateChannel method to return the mock client.
var relatieSoapClientProtectedMock = relatieSoapClientMock.Protected()
    .Setup<RelatieSoap>("CreateChannel")
    .Returns(relatieSoapMock.Object);
```