# How can I mock WCF client?

Tags: wcf

I have WCF client:

```
using (ServiceReference1.Service1Client host = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
{
    host.DoSomething();
}
```

I can't mock 'host' because it is type of ServiceReference1.Service1Client - it isn't interface.

I can set 'host' as a interface type:

```
using (ServiceReference1.IService1 host = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
{
    host.DoSomething();
}
```

But then I have error: **ServiceReference1.IService1 type used in a using statement must be implicity convertible to System.IDisposable.**

What can I do?

Comment: This does not help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062508/how-to-mock-wcf-client-using-moq

Comment: I can use ServiceReference1.IService1 but how can I then dispose service?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your IService1 implements IDisposable