# How to mock a webservice using ClientBase

Tags: c#, web-services, mocking

I am customer to a web service implemented with the following interface and inheritance:

```
public partial class FixLinkReportingServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<STPTradeRetriever.FixLinkReportingService.IFixLinkReportingService>, STPTradeRetriever.FixLinkReportingService.IFixLinkReportingService 
{
    ....
}
```

How should I go about mocking the object and in particular the ClientBase part ?

If I try to do the following:

```
public class FakeSuccessConnection : ClientBase<STPTradeRetriever.FixLinkReportingService.IFixLinkReportingService>,
        STPTradeRetriever.FixLinkReportingService.IFixLinkReportingService
{
}
```

It will complain about lacking endpoints in the app.config:

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'FixLinkReportingService.IFixLinkReportingService' 
in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or 
because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

Comment: Why not just mock the interface of the `STPTradeRetriever.FixLinkReportingService.IFixLinkReportingService` type?

Comment: I can but I cannot mock the connection to ClientBase<>

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14083347/2607840

Comment: I ended up doing a mock object implementing ICommunicationObject, IDisposable, STPTradeRetriever.FixLinkReportingService.IFixLinkReportingService which is exactly what you suggested in your link