# Unit Test - How to MOQ WCF Client using MOQ

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, moq

I've been looking at [many other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062508/how-to-mock-wcf-client-using-moq), many similar, but none seem to match the style of service reference, hence me asking.  Most of them talk about using ChannelFactory, but this one uses ClientBase.  I'm learning more about Unit testing & Moq.  I want to test our repository class, which makes a call to a WCF Service.

I've tried mocking this many ways, including creating a constructor on the repo, taking the FISP interface.

**How can I work this to be usable in the repo and also unit testable, mocking the WCF operation using moq?**

The **repository** didn't pass in the interface (yet), as below.  It's using the proxy client class.

```
public class FisPRepository : IFisPRepository
{
    private readonly FISPClient _fisPClient;

    public FisPRepository()
    {
        _fisPClient = new FISPClient
        {
            ClientCredentials =
            {

                UserName = {UserName = "xyz", Password = "cba"}
            }
        };

    public person GetPersonFromId(string id)
    {
        return _fisPClient.getPerson(new personRequest()
        {
            reference = new referenceFilter { type = "FWI", value = id },
        });
    }
}
```

### Generated reference

And here's the generated Reference code -

**Interface:**

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://www.aUrl.com/fwi", ConfigurationName="FISP.FISP")]
public interface FISP {
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://www.aUrl.com/fwi/FISP/getPersonRequest", ReplyAction="http://www.aUrl.com/fwi/FISP/getPersonResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(FhSoap.FISP.FWiException), Action="http://www.aUrl.com/fwi/FISP/getPerson/Fault/FWiException", Name="FWiException")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(episodeTask))]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="person")]
    FhSoap.FISP.getPersonResponse getPerson(FhSoap.FISP.getPersonRequest request);  
}
```

**Client:**

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface FISPChannel : FhSoap.FISP.FISP, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class FISPClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<FhSoap.FISP.FISP>, FhSoap.FISP.FISP {
    public FISPClient() {
    }

    public FISPClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    FhSoap.FISP.getPersonResponse FhSoap.FISP.FISP.getPerson(FhSoap.FISP.getPersonRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.getPerson(request);
    }

    public FhSoap.FISP.person getPerson(FhSoap.FISP.personRequest request) {
        FhSoap.FISP.getPersonRequest inValue = new FhSoap.FISP.getPersonRequest();
        inValue.request = request;
        FhSoap.FISP.getPersonResponse retVal = ((FhSoap.FISP.FISP)(this)).getPerson(inValue);
        return retVal.person;
    }
}
```

### Update

Following the suggestions in the comments below I tried using the interface to construct the client, is that what's meant?   As that doesn't then create a client, it creates a channel.

```
    public FisPRepository()
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<FISPChannel>("BasicHttpBinding_SomthingService");

        var credentialBehaviour = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
        credentialBehaviour.UserName.UserName = "xyz";
        credentialBehaviour.UserName.Password = "cba";

        _fisPClient = factory.CreateChannel();
    }
```

That **_fisPClient = factory.CreateChannel();** is invalid, as it it creates a FISPChannel, not client.  What am I missing?

Comment: your repository is working with your concrete client, you need to inject the client into the class onto an interface.

Comment: But that isnt an interface, so I cant mock it.

Comment: @DavidC, The client implements the interface so you can swap out the concrete class for the abstraction.

Comment: @Kritner, The FISPChannel? As opposed to the FISP interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> your repository is working with your concrete client, you need to inject the client into the class onto an interface

response:

> @Kritner, The FISPChannel? As opposed to the FISP interface?

Well, the normal convention is for interfaces to be "I" something like `IFISP`, but either way, the `IFISP` interface is what I would have used in the past (instead of the `IFISPChannel`. Though currently, if you attempted to use `FISP`, that interface would not have access to the `ClientCredentials` that you're currently setting in the class when newing up the client.

Ideally, you would not be setting your credentials on each repository, but in some sort of configuration.  Once you've done that, you can refactor to something like this:

```
public class FisPRepository : IFisPRepository
{
    private readonly FISP _fisp;

    public FisPRepository(FISP fisp)
    {
        _fisp = fisp;
    }

    public person GetPersonFromId(string id)
    {
        return _fisP.getPerson(new personRequest()
        {
            reference = new referenceFilter { type = "FWI", value = id },
        });
    }
}
```

and of course, when constructing your repository, you'll need to pass in a concretion of the client - but for unit testing you'll be able to mock the `FISP`.

You can get a concretion of the client in several ways.

- Use an IOC container like Ninject, Unity, AutoFac, etc
- New up the concretion directly
- Use service location

As syntax differs depending on your IOC or service location, so here's how you could get a repository now directly:

```
FisPRepository myRepo = new FisPRepository(new FISPClient());
```

injecting your concretion and coding to an abstraction is a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) known as dependency injection.