# Is it possible to UnitTest WCF connections?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, wcf

I've implemented a mechanism to detect, and try to reconnect to a WCF service on which the connection has been broken.

Is it possible to UnitTest a connection loss, between a client and a server(which are both launched in the UnitTest)?

It should work on every computer on which the UnitTest could be launched(which mean dev computers+build machine).

I've searched for a while but didn't found any conclusive way of doing it(in C# at least).

Comment: connectivity is an implementation concern that can be abstracted which should allow for mocking connection loss. All depends on your design.

Comment: @Nkosi On high level, this is mocked. But here, I'm trying to test the part that directly interacts with the WCF ChannelFactory, to ensure that the correct exception are caught, that the channels are in the correct states, ...

Comment: Then why not have the mock throw the desired exception?

Comment: @Nkosi ... how do you mock a ChannelFactory? like I've already said, on high level, it has already been tested. But this just ensure that the exception I decided to throw is caught, and by example, I just saw that I was expecting my channel to be faulted in a specific state, which at the end is not the case. So I want to UnitTest this specific case. Anyway, I'm not asking if I should UnitTest it or not, but how.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of the subject under test and the service so that a possible example of a unit test can be constructed.

Comment: Found two example from a quick search [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062508/how-to-mock-wcf-client-using-moq#14083347) and [here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1501/mocking-wcf-services-using-moq.aspx)

Comment: @Nkosi This doesn't test the connectivity exceptions. You're not answering to my question at all.